# Would a raspberry pi be strong enough to work as a reverse proxy for multiple web servers

Tags: server

First time poster, so this may be an easy question. I currently have two web servers serving a total of four web applications, mostly for my own personal testing and development. I'm running under through one public IP address, so I have an old Dell Poweredge server ca. 2005 (1.8 GHz P4 processor, 4GB Ram) set up as a reverse proxy to direct requests to the two web servers.

The reverse proxy is very simple - 32bit Ubuntu Server 12.04 with Apache running with the proper mod_proxy configuration. However, because the machine is fairly old, it runs very loud and consumes more power than what I would like, considering all it does is proxy requests through Apache.

So my question: would a Raspberry Pi be powerful enough to serve the same purpose? My main concern is that one of the web applications is OwnCloud, a personal cloud application that transfers and syncs files, mostly office-type files with some video and music streaming, almost 24/7. Obviously a Raspberry Pi would be a much quieter, more efficient solution than what I have right now, so I would like to try it if it can handle the task well from a performance perspective.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: guess this depends on how much traffic the proxy gets. With the pi you'll most likely be limited to 10/100 Ethernet speeds and don't expect too much throughput because of cheap parts and the Pi's ethernet controller is wired via the USB Bus.

Comment: Do it! Make your dreams come true!

Comment: How many Mbps are you running for your overall traffic load through the proxy?